# How to refresh a form when a macro is updated in ms access

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, macros

I have a form with 2 fields. I have a macro in the on change and after update event on the first field which says when field1 = x, then field2 = y. I have added few records on the form by choosing x on field 1 and field2 populated with y. Now I updated the macro to say if field1 is x then field2 should be z. How do I make all the records that I already entered in the form to change the field2 value from y to z?

Comment: By creating and running an update query. PS why are you using two macros, no need for that. Delete the On Change macro. PPS use VBA, not macros.

Comment: @Rene thank you for your response. May I know why you down voted my question please

Comment: ? I did not down vote

Comment: @Rene ok thank you. For some reason my question was voted down which prevents me from asking more questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create and run an update query. PS why are you using two macros, no need for that. Delete the On Change macro. PPS use VBA, not macros

Comment: This is an existing database which already had macro created. Thank you for the response. I will run the update query.